# Is this comma correctly used?

Tags: punctuation, clauses

> I love to dance and sing, to laugh and play.

Is this punctuated correctly? They are dependent clauses and all...

Comment: Grammatically it's fine. Idiomatically, native speakers today [are more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+sing+and+dance%2Cto+dance+and+sing&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20sing%20and%20dance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20dance%20and%20sing%3B%2Cc0) to *sing and dance*, but I've no idea why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Because their English teachers gave them "the ol' song and dance".

Comment: It sounds far better than the equally 'grammatical' "I love to dance and to sing and to laugh and to play." and "I love to dance, sing, laugh and play."

Answer (score 1):

> *I love to dance and sing, to laugh and play.*

The way you have punctuated this, I'd interpret it to mean that you frequently sing while you dance, and you frequently laugh while you play, and that you particularly enjoy these two kinds of frolicking.

(That doesn't mean that you **never** dance without singing, or sing without dancing, or that you **don't** enjoy dancing silently. You've given a very simple and brief statement, and I've told you how I would interpret it.)

Change the wording and the comma structure, though, and I'd interpret it slightly differently:

> *I love to dance, sing, laugh and play*.

Now it looks like you have **four** activities you like to engage in, as opposed to the two hand-in-hand activities mentioned in your original.

As for "Is it punctuated correctly?" you might have asked the wrong question there. Lots of things in English are acceptable; oftentimes, it isn't a matter of *can* we do this, but more a matter of *what does it mean* when we do this.